# How to implement TabHost sliding effect?

Tags: android, animation, android-tabhost, android-sliding

I need to create some TabHost form paging. There is sliding animation effects in TabHost column when switching options page.

I want to implement the page also has sliding animation effects. How to so this? I check the reference it said using Tabhost or ActivityGround. But I do not know how to do.

Is anyone can give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: You can do this by using `ViewPager` and `PageIndicator`.