# tabhost implement sliding effects

Tags: android, animation, android-tabhost

I tried to use this solution:
[How to implement TabHost sliding effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352954/how-to-implement-tabhost-sliding-effect)

but doesnt do anything, i mean that everything remain the same.
the implementation i think is very simple:

i include here the code solution:

```
import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

/**
 * A custom OnTabChangeListener that uses the TabHost its related to to fetch information about the current and previous
 * tabs. It uses this information to perform some custom animations that slide the tabs in and out from left and right.
 * 
 * @author Daniel Kvist
 * 
 */
public class AnimatedTabHostListener implements OnTabChangeListener
{

    private static final int ANIMATION_TIME = 240;
    private TabHost tabHost;
    private View previousView;
    private View currentView;
    private int currentTab;

    /**
     * Constructor that takes the TabHost as a parameter and sets previousView to the currentView at instantiation
     * 
     * @param tabHost
     */
    public AnimatedTabHostListener(TabHost tabHost)
    {
        this.tabHost = tabHost;
        this.previousView = tabHost.getCurrentView();
    }

    /**
     * When tabs change we fetch the current view that we are animating to and animate it and the previous view in the
     * appropriate directions.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {

        currentView = tabHost.getCurrentView();
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() > currentTab)
        {
            previousView.setAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
            currentView.setAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
        }
        else
        {
            previousView.setAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
            currentView.setAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
        }
        previousView = currentView;
        currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

    }

    /**
     * Custom animation that animates in from right
     * 
     * @return Animation the Animation object
     */
    private Animation inFromRightAnimation()
    {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        return setProperties(inFromRight);
    }

    /**
     * Custom animation that animates out to the right
     * 
     * @return Animation the Animation object
     */
    private Animation outToRightAnimation()
    {
        Animation outToRight = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        return setProperties(outToRight);
    }

    /**
     * Custom animation that animates in from left
     * 
     * @return Animation the Animation object
     */
    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation()
    {
        Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        return setProperties(inFromLeft);
    }

    /**
     * Custom animation that animates out to the left
     * 
     * @return Animation the Animation object
     */
    private Animation outToLeftAnimation()
    {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        return setProperties(outtoLeft);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that sets some common properties
     * @param animation the animation to give common properties
     * @return the animation with common properties
     */
    private Animation setProperties(Animation animation)
    {
        animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return animation;
    }
}
```

so just create an `AnimatedTabHostListener` object and give it to the tabHost by the `setOnTabChangedListener()` method
I debugged and the method of the listener are called... but i dont see any animations. how it is possibile?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from github https://github.com/jittya/SwipeableTabView

**Java Code** :

```
LinearLayout SwipableViewTabConntainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.SwipableTabViewContainer);
        ArrayList<String> titles=new ArrayList<String>();
        titles.add("One");
        titles.add("Two");
        titles.add("Three");
        titles.add("Four");
        titles.add("Five");


        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for(int i=0;i<titles.size();i++)
        {
            fragments.add(new Dummyfragment(titles.get(i)));
        }

        SwipeTabView swipeTabView=new SwipeTabView(this,titles,fragments,getSupportFragmentManager());
        SwipableViewTabConntainer.addView(swipeTabView);
```

**Xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SwipableTabViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think it works just with 'FragmentActivity' i'm working inside a fragment. The point is that in a fragment i cannot use getSupportFragmentManager(), in a FragmentActivity yes...

Comment: its also work with fragment but activity should be fragmentActivity.